# Flutter desktop embedding

Tags: macos, flutter, dart

Following [these instructions](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding)

I tried to run a new project on macOS(desktop) using Android Studio.

I get the following error:

> Launching lib/main.dart on macOS in release mode... Finished with
>   error: Unable to get Xcode project information:  xcodebuild: error:
>   The directory
>   /Users/current.user/Work/Playground/testout/flutter_app2/macos does
>   not contain an Xcode project, workspace or package.

I get the same issue if I run in the terminal `flutter run --release -d macOS`

Running on a simulator/device, works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't sound like you followed [the instructions for running a project other than the FDE example](https://github.com/google/flutter-desktop-embedding/blob/master/README.md#running-other-flutter-projects). A newly created Flutter project doesn't have support for running on desktop; you need to add that.

See also [flutter.dev/desktop#create](https://flutter.dev/desktop#create) for information on the state of `create` and `run` for desktop.